# Neo4j foreach clause to loop through elements of string array

Tags: arrays, string, loops, neo4j, cypher

I have some nodes which contain a string field. This string field is a list of pks each of which represents the pk of another node. I want to loop through this string list and convert all the pks to their respective name. For example:

```
MATCH (r:Recipe) RETURN r.ingredients_list AS ingredients_list LIMIT 1;
```

Might return this:

| ingredients_list |
| --- |
| "Ingredients: 8572629, 1049724, 0494828, 0598371, 6168492, 0986423" |

And I want to convert it to this:

| ingredients_list |
| --- |
| "Ingredients: flour, milk, eggs, butter, baking soda, sugar" |

I have so far managed to get the string list and split it into an array:

```
WITH "Ingredients: " AS s MATCH (r:Recipes) WHERE r.ingredients_list ~= "Ingredients: .*"
WITH SPLIT(SUBSTRING(r.ingredients_list, SIZE(s), SIZE(r.ingredients_list)), ",")
AS string_arrays RETURN string_arrays;
```

| string_arrays |
| --- |
| ["8572629", "1049724", "0494828", "0598371", "6168492", "0986423"] |

And I can individually match each pk to its corresponding ingredient node and extract the name:

```
MATCH (g:Ingredient) WHERE g.pk = "0494828" RETURN g.name;
```

But I am stumped as to how I can loop through these string arrays. I believe I want something like the `reduce` function to loop through the each subarray, query the :Ingredient nodes to find the correct name, and then do a string join to put everything into a string again. But the accumulator only seems to operate on nodes. The same goes for Neo's `FOREACH`.

Is there a function which loops through elements of a string array? Or some other neo function to perform an operation on all the elements of an array of strings rather than an array of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `UNWIND`.

> With `UNWIND`, you can transform any list back into individual rows. These lists can be parameters that were passed in, previously `collect`-ed result or other list expressions.
> https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.3/clauses/unwind/

With `UNWIND` you can turn `string_arrays` into individual rows, perform `MATCH` to find the name, and finally aggregate the names as a list:

```
UNWIND string_arrays AS pk
MATCH (g:Ingredient) WHERE g.pk = pk
RETURN collect(g.name) AS names
```

However, if you already have multiple rows with `MATCH (r:Recipe)`, this probably would mix up the lists. So you might need to call `UNWIND` within a [subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.3/clauses/call-subquery/):

```
WITH "Ingredients: " AS s
MATCH (r:Recipes) WHERE r.ingredients_list ~= "Ingredients: .*"
WITH split(substring(r.ingredients_list, size(s), size(r.ingredients_list))) AS string_arrays
CALL {
  WITH string_arrays
  UNWIND string_arrays AS pk
  MATCH (g:Ingredient) WHERE g.pk = pk
  RETURN collect(g.name) AS names
}
RETURN names
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH "Ingredients: " AS s
MATCH (r:Recipes) WHERE r.ingredients_list ~=           "Ingredients: .*"
// carry along the r to keep the recipes apart
WITH r,split(substring(r.ingredients_list, size(s), size(r.ingredients_list))) AS string_arrays

UNWIND string_arrays AS pk

MATCH (g:Ingredient) WHERE g.pk = pk

// return the Recipes node (or just its id) and the ingredient names
RETURN r,collect(g.name) AS names
```